# zsh: Variable gets unset without reason

Tags: zsh, variable, debugging, bugs, typeset

Somehow `v` gets unset after calling `f`.

```
$ zsh -xc 'v=1; f() { local v; v=2 true; }; f; typeset -p v'
+zsh:1> v=1
+zsh:1> f
+f:0> local v
+f:0> v=2 +f:0> true
+zsh:1> typeset -p v
zsh:typeset:1: no such variable: v
```

Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/NightMachinary/32689e786a3b7f5865a042d49b884b57) of my original reproduction report.

I did [email zsh-workers@zsh.org](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2019/msg00678.html), but I have yet to receive any replies.

Comment: A bug indeed. A shorter reproducer: `zsh -c 'v=1; f() { local v; v=2 true; }; f; typeset -p v'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a bug indeed. You did right the right thing to report it.

It was then fixed by this commit: https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/d946f22a4cd2eed0f3a67881cfa57c805703929c/ which will be included in the next version.

And here's [the explanation from `zsh`'s maintainer](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2019/msg00700.html):

> ```
> On Wed, 2019-08-14 at 10:37 +0100, Stephane Chazelas wrote:
> > 2019-08-08 20:38:05 +0430, Aryn Starr:
> > Now, that being said, as discussed on U&L it looks like a bug
> > indeed and a shorter reproducer is:
> > 
> > $ zsh -xc 'v=1; f() { local v; v=2 true; }; f; typeset -p v'
> > +zsh:1> v=1
> > +zsh:1> f
> > +f:0> local v
> > +f:0> v=2 +f:0> true
> > +zsh:1> typeset -p v
> > zsh:typeset:1: no such variable: v
> > 
> > Most likely, that's the "v=2 true" (where "true" is a builtin) that ends up
> > unsetting the "v" from the global scope.
>
> Yes, the saved version of "v" that we restore after the builtin is
> missing the pointer back to the version of v in the enclosing scope.  So
> it's not only not shown as set, it will leak memory.
>
> This simply preserves that pointer in the copy, but this assumes we've
> correctly blocked off the old parameter from being altered inside the
> function scope --- if we haven't that preserved old pointer is going to
> get us into trouble.  However, if we haven't that's already a bug, so
> this shouldn't make things worse.
>
> pws
> ```
>
> [patch skipped]